# Azure OpenID get city

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, blazor-server-side

I have a Balzor-sever application that calls the Microsoft Graph API for a signed-in user. I followed Microsoft [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/) to implement that, my startup page has this code.

```
services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
    .AddMicrosoftGraph(Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

My `initialScopes` are `User.Read, GroupMember.Read.All`. 
I want to use `AuthenticationStateProvider` to get city because when I inject `GraphServiceClient` as service and tried to use it I get some error, that no one has logged in yet! Something like this

```
 using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization;
 public class AuthService : IAuthService
    {
        private readonly AuthenticationStateProvider authenticationStateProvider;

        public AuthService(AuthenticationStateProvider authenticationStateProvider)
        {
            this.authenticationStateProvider = authenticationStateProvider;
        }
        public async ValueTask<UserConfiguration> GetUserInfo()
        {
            //Here I would like to get city also in the claims
            var authState = await authenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
         ......
        }
    }
```

In my startup, I have this:

```
services.AddScoped<IAuthService, AuthService>();
```

**My question, how can I get the city of logged in suer?**

I tried to add different scopes like `"Directory.Read.All"` and granted them as application permission and delegated permission but it didn't work.

Thanks.

Comment: only `User.Read` is required.

Answer (score 2):

For Ms [graph api get user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#response), it is able to return the city property, but you have to use Odata query parameter `select` to get it from the api response. By the way, I used sample code from [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-blazor-server/tree/main/WebApp-graph-user/Call-MSGraph/blazorserver-calls-MS-graph).

[image]

Then in your code, when using graph SDK you should write code like this and it worked for me:

```
_user = await GraphClient.Me.Request().Select("DisplayName, city").GetAsync();
```

[image]
[image]

I have a razor component like this:

```
@page "/showprofile"

@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@attribute [Authorize]
@inherits UserProfileBase

<h3>User Profile</h3>
@{
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Property</th>
                <th>Value</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr>
            <td> DisplayName </td>
            <td> @_user.DisplayName </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> User city </td>
            <td> @_user.City </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
 }
```

And have a base file `UserProfileBase.cs` like this:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BlazorServerAad.Pages
{
    public class UserProfileBase : ComponentBase
    {
        [Inject]
        GraphServiceClient GraphClient { get; set; }
        [Inject]
        MicrosoftIdentityConsentAndConditionalAccessHandler ConsentHandler { get; set; }

        protected User _user = new User();
        protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
            await GetUserProfile();
        }

        private async Task GetUserProfile()
        {
            try
            {
                _user = await GraphClient.Me.Request().Select("DisplayName, city").GetAsync();
                var a = "1";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                ConsentHandler.HandleException(ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer. Maybe I have to adjust my question a little. I want to use `AuthenticationStateProvider` because when I inject `GraphServiceClient` as service and tried to use it I get some error, that no one has logged in yet!

Comment: Thank you for your reply `no one has logged in yet` you require to let users sign in first so that you can call graph api.... hmmm. I'm not so sure what's your question now.. But anyway, you can follow the sample I shared in the link to test in your side, the sample is provide in [official sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v2-code#web-applications).

Comment: This the scenario that I follow, User has to log in, then Azure AD communicate with Graph, then I can get info about user by using `AuthenticationStateProvider `,  I want to use this info in the startup page to prepare my `httpclient` that calls another api

Comment: But I even can't find `AuthenticationStateProvider` in the link you shared in the question. Per my understanding, we can only use graphclient to call graph api when we use graph SDK....

Comment: Pleas, see my update.

Comment: You can see from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.authorization.authenticationstateprovider.getauthenticationstateasync?view=aspnetcore-7.0) that `GetAuthenticationStateAsync` won't give you the `City` property, I'm afraid you have to to get it via  calling ms graph api